# Different behaviour lm in stat_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782571/different-colours-in-ggplot-based-on-geom-smooth/31782791#31782791) question someone asked if it is possible change the colour in a `ggplot2` plot depending on a linear regression line.

The proposed solution worked, the points have a different colour above and below the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(2015)
df <-  data.frame(x = rnorm(100),
                  y = rnorm(100))


# Fit linear regression
l = lm(y ~ x, data = df)

# Make new group variable based on residuals
df$group = NA
df$group[which(l$residuals >= 0)] = "above"
df$group[which(l$residuals < 0)] = "below"

# Make the plot
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = group)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x)
```

[image: Expected output]

But I would like to do regression for `y-1`. As asked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480566/adding-an-offset-to-stat-smooth?rq=1) question.

```
# Fit linear regression
l = lm(y - 1 ~ x, data = df)

# Make new group variable based on residuals
df$group = NA
df$group[which(l$residuals >= 0)] = "above"
df$group[which(l$residuals < 0)] = "below"

# Make the plot
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = group)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y - 1 ~ x)
```

[image]

This is not what I expected. It looks to me that `stat_smooth` did what expected. The `lm` however gives the same result for `y ~ x` and `y - 1 ~ x`

What am I missing here?

Comment: What did you expect to happen?  Notice that the intercept of the second model is shifted down by 1 unit - this is what happens when there is a "location shift" in the response variable.

Comment: Because your regression has an intercept, the actual fit is the same in all cases (corresponding residuals too). For what you want, calculate groups based on the residual compared to -1, not 0.

Comment: Thanks, of course I have to calculated the residuals with -1 in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to color points based on where they lie according to the line, you can try comparing the actual value to the predicted value rather than using the residual

```
df$group = NA
df$group[df$y>predict(l)] = "above"
df$group[df$y<predict(l)] = "below"
```

Comment: I think you `-1` and not `1` because in the questions it's `y - 1`.

Comment: @jeroen81 I don't understand your comment. I'm not doing any arithmetic here. I'm just comparing the y's on the original scale to the predicted value from the fitted model. That's the variable `l` not the number `1`.

Comment: Sorry my bad, looked like a 1 on my very small screen.